# Why does my fixed positioning no longer work?

Tags: css, css-position, perspective

I'm having issues with fixed positioning and 3d transforms, where elements don't appear to respect positioning and other properties when its parent element has perspective and preserve-3d applied to it:

```
.perspective {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 600px;
}
```

Different results in Chrome and IE11 so far. I have a simple test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/brdvnaf8/

When I remove the perspective, positioning works fine. When I apply the perspective to the `.parent` element off all child nodes, positioning works fine. When I apply perspective to only one child node, it's not fine.

Can anyone explain how this is (or isn't) working for individually wrapped child nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on linux machine, so I don't have **IE11** browser to test, but I think I know where is the problem. If Chrome and IE11 behave differently than I suppose it is a bug in one of them.
I tested on **Chrome** and everything is OK. It respects the **W3C** specification.

So where is the catch ? Some of **CSS transform properties** result in creation of **containing block** even for **fixed positioned elements**. 
So be aware of that.

Here are some of **CSS propery/value** pairs that **create containing block even for fixed positioned elements**:

**will-change: transform;**

**transform:** any value other than auto

**perspective:** any value other than zero(0)

**transform-style: preserve-3d**

I think there are some more but I don't have time to consult the spec in depth. So that is the problem I think.

**Here are some blog posts about this stuff:**

[Un-fixing Fixed Elements with CSS Transforms](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/)

[Some Gotchas That Got Me](http://aerotwist.com/blog/some-gotchas-that-got-me/)

Comment: Good reads, thanks @Blago Ereš. Looks like what Eric Meyer describes is what's going on in my case. Rather annoying, and unworkable, but at least I know that now :)